# Notation for the summation of the cumulative product of each row of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

What steps should I take to achieve the desired outcome?

Given a matrix $A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 3 & 5\\ 1 & 4 & 11\end{array}\right]$, the steps should result in a scalar $x$ equal to the summation of the  products of each row, i.e., for this $A$, $x = (2*3*5) + (1*4*11) = 74$.

I think it is called the cumulative product operation in MATLAB.

There must be some established notation as it such a simple concept.